# 2e display disappeared after reboot

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a 2e display (Samsung SyncMaster 2493hm) on my laptop (Asus f551m) with dual boot (Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04). Of this dual boot I use 99.9% of the time Ubuntu, which I rarely need to reboot. However, after a month or so, I thought it would be a good idea to switch it off for the night.

Now, after booting the 2e display is not detected. Nothing happened to either the laptop or the cable or the monitor besides turning it off.

I swapped the cable (hdmi) with a brand new one (so not tested and have no other means to test) but without effect.

The display checks all ports, doesn't find hdmi and then shows check signal cable.

I googled to see if I could find a way to find the display via terminal but that search came up empty, but I tried the following command:

```
sudo find . -type f -name "*displays*"
```

and of course tried to "detect display" via system settings.

Does anybody have an idea how to find the cause for this or how to solve it?

Comment: just like to add that the issue continues and that this is not some simple error by a newby. any thoughts on the matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem lays within the monitor itself.

Apparently the HDMI cable didn't make contact with the ground. solved this after attaching a VGA cable while the HDMI was still connected. As soon as the VGA cable made ground the HDMI image appeared (without the VGA actually connected, ground was enough)